# Recursive function returns None but prints correct result

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am working on recursive function that fills a list. I encountered a problem that when I try to return the list itself I recieve `None` argument. However, if I print the same argument I got the correct list back. Any idea why I see such behavour?

Example:

```
def Price(tau, price):

price[tau] = (tau**2 - tau) + price[tau+1] - price[tau+2]

if tau == 0:
    return price

else:
    tau = tau - 1
    Price(tau, price)



print(Price(tau = 3,
            price = 6*[0]))

> None
```

However **just prining the price**, gives correct result:

```
def Price(tau, price):

price[tau] = (tau**2 - tau) + price[tau+1] - price[tau+2]

if tau == 0:
    print(price)

else:
    tau = tau - 1
    Price(tau, price)



Price(tau = 3,
      price = 6*[0])

> [-6, 2, 8, 6, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your function, you are only returning the result of `Price` when you go into your `if` statement. If you hit your `else` statement, you do indeed go one step deeper into the recursive loop, but you never return that result. Try this instead:

```py
if tau == 0:
    return price

else:
    tau = tau - 1
    return Price(tau, price)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GreenyellowPutridFinance)

Comment: We've all been there! *"To understand recursion, one first must understand recursion."* (Please remember to accept the answer if it addresses your question.)