# Recursive depth first search returns None but can print correct path

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I can print the correct result with the commented out print statement, but the return statement returns None. Why is this and how can I fix it?

I read over this answer: [Recursive function returns None but prints correct result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380558/recursive-function-returns-none-but-prints-correct-result)

But afaik, shouldn't my last line return final_path be returning something when the if does not happen?

Also, are my variable names OK? path, copy_path and final_path don't look super clear to me but I can't think of better names.

```
def dfs_route_finder(self, starting_vertex: int, destination_vertex:int, visited_nodes: List[bool]=None, path: List[int]=None) -> List[int]:
        if visited_nodes is None:
            visited_nodes = set()
        if path is None:
            path = []
        visited_nodes.add(starting_vertex)
        copy_path = path.copy() # only want to keep branch if it is on the way to destination 
        copy_path.append(starting_vertex)
        print(starting_vertex, destination_vertex, copy_path)
        if starting_vertex == destination_vertex:
            # print(copy_path)
            return copy_path
        else:
            for neighbor in self.get_neighbors(starting_vertex):
                if neighbor not in visited_nodes:
                    final_path = self.dfs_route_finder(neighbor, destination_vertex, visited_nodes, copy_path)
                    if final_path:
                        print("final_path",final_path)
                        return final_path

    def dfs_recursive(self, starting_vertex: int, destination_vertex: int) -> List[int]:
        """
        Return a list containing a path from
        starting_vertex to destination_vertex in
        depth-first order.

        This should be done using recursion.
        """
        self.dfs_route_finder(starting_vertex, destination_vertex)
```

EDIT: The dfs_recursive function fails because it is not returning something, it should be:

```
        return self.dfs_route_finder(starting_vertex, destination_vertex)
```

Comment: *shouldn't my last line return final_path be returning something when the if does not happen?* -- no, because it's inside the `if` block.  If you make it through all the neighbors without hitting any of those, your function will return `None`.

Comment: Ok, so I tried wrapping the for loop in an else but that still returns None and prints the correct path if I print(final_path). I don't understand why this is still broken.

Comment: Just wrapping it in an else doesn't fix the issue.  What do you want the function to return if it doesn't return anything from inside that for loop?  You need to put that at the end, and it needs to be outside the for loop.

Comment: Ok I just realized I am not passing my unit tests because dfs_recursive does not return anything. It works once it returns         self.dfs_route_finder(starting_vertex, destination_vertex)
. 

I tried with both Return None aligned with the else at the very end and not and it seems to default to None if there's no path either way. 

Thanks for your patience @Samwise